# How can I make it so that only the case owner can see my quick action?

Tags: lightning, case, quickaction

I have a a quick action on a Case lightning record page that I need to make only visible to the owner of the record. I have dynamic actions enabled, so I can access the user record and the case record's fields in the visibility logic, but since it only seems to let you compare one of those values with a hardcoded value, I can't figure out how to compare the user with the owner of the case. Is there a way that I can quickly do this within the visibility or settings or will I have to go out and create something like a custom field on case to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Create a checkbox formula field on the Case

```
Is_Owned_By_Running_User__c

with formula expression:  OwnerId = $User.Id
```

Then use that formula field in the dynamic action visibility filter

Comment: Our case fields are highly limited, so I'd really like to avoid adding a new one. I think there are some custom fields that do something close to that (they return true for a few additional people), so I might have to end up using one of those.